# Английский текст в форме отправки вопроса висит уже полгода. Уберите его наконец оттуда

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нытьё

В Мете конечно тоже самое.

Уже пора, пора наконец взять в руки текстовый редактор, найти в шаблоне эту проклятую строчку и заменить её на что-то более подходящее:

- "Что, опять не компилируется? А я то здесь при чем?"
- "Здесь не переводят из Pascal в C++."
- "Выражайтесь яснее. Штатные экстрасенсы в отпуске."

И баннер заодно этот мерзкий выпилить оттуда.

[image: annoying_bug]

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Отправился трясти ответственных разработчиков в личном порядке.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: скажите, что русская мафия ими недовольна.